# angular6 reusable drop down with object binding

Tags: angular

I would like to have reusable drop down component which would help me to bind object to it, I have same but it simply takes array as @input to dropdown, I would like to have object binded to dropdown so I can get id out of selected or changed choice.

Object could be like below:

```
   {
    name:'test'
    class:'A1'
    id:'d1' }
```

I  know you could use [ngValue] in this scenario but how we should use it in our main reusable component and how we should use it applying component.

if somebody can shared some thought or working example please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ControlValueAccessor in your dropdown component to work with `[(ngModel)]` and Angular Forms.

Here is a great tutorial how to do this
https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/

Answer (score 0):

You can bind object to select using inbuit angular pipe KeyValue.. and then you can simply fire (change) event of selection change. complete working example you can found here in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f7zj5s)

Your Object is...

```
dp = {
  'name':'test',
  'class':'A1',
  'id':'d1' 
};
```

Your select Html is...

```
<select (change)="onSelect($event)">
   <option>select</option>
   <option *ngFor="let key of dp | keyvalue" [value]="key.key">{{ key.value}} </option>
</select>
```

Your onSelect Change event function gets changing key...

```
onSelect(event){
  this.value = event.target.value;
}
```